# Colocar título a las tablas en bootstrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap

En mi vista utilizo Bootstrap y en una ventana modal muestro varias tablas con información diferente.
Pero mis tablas no tienen título. Cómo hago para ponerles un título a cada una de ellas?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
            <tr class="info">
                <th>cabecera1</th>
                <th>cabecera2</th>
                <th>cabecera3</th>
                <th>cabecera4</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>dato1</td>
                <td>dato2</td>
                <td>dato3</td>
                <td>dato4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
            <tr class="info">
                <th>cabecera1</th>
                <th>cabecera2</th>
                <th>cabecera3</th>
                <th>cabecera4</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>dato1</td>
                <td>dato2</td>
                <td>dato3</td>
                <td>dato4</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las tablas en `Bootstrap` no tienen titulo, en tu caso puedes agregar una etiqueta `<h1>` antes de la tabla para agregarles dicho titulo. Como recomendacion utiliza las etiquetas `thead` y `tbody` para crear las cabeceras y el cuerpo de la tabla.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    <h1>Titulo de la tabla </h1>
    <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
      <thead>
        <tr class="info">
          <th>cabecera1</th>
          <th>cabecera2</th>
          <th>cabecera3</th>
          <th>cabecera4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>dato1</td>
          <td>dato2</td>
          <td>dato3</td>
          <td>dato4</td>
        </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Para mas informacion sobre las tablas en `Bootstrap` te dejo el link de su [documentacion](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/).

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar por ejemplo una etiqueta de encabezado (y adaptarlo con css):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <h2>Aquí el título</h2> <!-- encabezado de tabla -->
        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
            <tr class="info">
                <th>cabecera1</th>
                ...
```

O también puedes agregar un `tr` que ocupe todas las columnas:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
            <tr> <!-- encabezado de tabla -->
               <td colspan="4">Aquí el título</td> 
            </tr>
            <tr class="info">
                <th>cabecera1</th>
                ...
```

Con esto último verás algo como:

[image: Tabla con título]

Saludos!